# Is there evidence that programming will die/not-die because of LowCode/NoCode?

Tags: development-process, source-code

I have to do a presentation of `Convertigo`, a `LowCode/NoCode` platform, for my IT class. I did a lot of research on it.

What do developers think about a platform that permits to everyone to create an app? During my research, the first idea which came to me was "programming will die". But as a developer I don't know what to think about that.

A lot of websites are pro `NoCode`, they defend it so it's not really objective. I know that we can be better with the `LowCode` side of, for example, `Convertigo`, and create custom components with our knowledge in code. But how far can this take us?

They said that a platform like this can improve our skills and speed. We're using LowCode with `Android Studio LayoutEditor`, and other tools, to make us faster. But is it going to far?

Comment: It's been tried many many times. It always turns out that you need code. BTW the original "no code" system was called an assembler. The next one was called a compiler.

Comment: Yeha closed while making an answer. Honestly this LowCode software seems to be the new generation of things what already existed long ago, they just changed the name. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-aided_software_engineering since they already existed since long ago and we're still coding, you have a factual answer to your question instand of an opinion...

Comment: When my father started working as a programmer in 1970, people already told him "That's a bad choice, in a few years you can just ask the computer what you want and programmers will no longer be necessary!". More than 50 years later, we need more programmers than ever. There is no way that all software will ever be built using low-code / no-code frameworks, and programming is not going to die because of this.

Comment: The abstraction level of programming rises continuously. A language like Python would be considered "no code" by the machine-code programmers of the 1950's. But regardless of abstraction level, someone need to translate ideas and vague requirements into some formalized and unambiguous system. And of course someone needs to develop the platforms.

Comment: It's interesting that CASE tools still exist - git is a CASE tool - it's just that nobody tries to do software engineering *without* a computer any more.

Comment: Anyone remember Apple's HyperCard? Turned out that you could create apps with it without being a software developer, but only real software developers could create apps that worked.

Comment: @gnasher729 as is the case with most of these tools. Because they are just code that doesn't look like code to a casual observer.

Comment: IMHO "Low code" is nothing but the new marketing buzzword for what was  formerly known under the name [4GL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth-generation_programming_language), see also the low-code section in that Wikipedia article. In the ~40 years since the 4GL idea existed, I have not seen 4GL tools to replace programming (they may have accompanied programming to some degree, but that's all).

Comment: Do you know what the term for a software specification sufficiently detailed enough for a computer to understand is? *Code*. That *Code* might be pictorial, it might be text, or a string of numbers. It might be very abstract, it might be a configuration file, or the processors native language, but it is all code. Anyone who wants to write code is by definition a programmer, in the same way that anyone who puts pen to paper is a writer. There is a gulf of skill between being a writer, and being an author. That skill gulf is also there between a lay programmer and a software developer.

Answer (score 9):

Forty years ago a piece of "no code" software was released called ["The Last One"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_One_(software)), with the idea that it would be the last program that needed to be written.

This turned out not to be the case.

LowCode/NoCode tools have their place as onramps for developement, and convenient ways to automate workflows. One of the most effective no code tools in widespread use is the event-propagating functional language known as "Microsoft Excel", which contains an entire programming language and can load modules written in conventional programming languages.

But the fundamental complexity of working out what the program should do and how different functionality should interact appears to be hard to reduce. There's always going to be a role like "analyst" to translate vague human desires and imprecise processes into computer language.

Comment: Wow, really interesting, i'll take a look on this story. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I vaguely remember "the last programming tool you will ever buy" and a review "the last programming tool you should ever buy".

Answer (score 3):

Full code always comes to the rescue. LowCode/NoCode platforms are good at disguising it, and can probably solve 80% of surface needs. LowCode is a market term, not computer science.

You can only do "everything" if you have a turing-complete language/compiler. If a LowCode/NoCode platform happens to be turing-complete (which none are), that's because it's a "language" that doesn't look like lines of code. The code/compiler is still there, but it's disguised. BTW, with addition of Lambdas, Microsoft Excel itself (without macros) is now apparently turing-complete.

Convertigo seems to be a data-forms driven platform. In fact, all LowCode platforms are data-forms driven. If you want to integrate with a particular third-party service, someone needs to do the code - either the vendor who add support, or they provide an SDK so you can do it. At first glance, I don't see that convertigo let you make your own components, but they do expose their backend API - https://www.convertigo.com/convertigo-sdk/

Comment: And you ***always*** encounter some situation that can only be solved by writing code. And as your product gets more and more complex, you have more and more of those situations... until most of your product is code.

Comment: Yes you're right, to create our custom component i was talking about other "nocode" platform like wordpress for example. You have all the tools to create a website but you can also custom your tools with a bit of knowledge.

Comment: And yes developer will always be useful, but on an other plan i guess. Code will evolve situation too.

Comment: This will only change when we have artificial intelligence. I mean real artificial _intelligence_. But then I fear that artificial intelligence will detect FaceBook and start losing all its intelligence.